# How can I get subtitles downloaded from Firebase Storage (as .srt file) to show up in Android VideoView?

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-storage, subtitle

Here is my code:

```
var videoView : VideoView = findViewById(R.id.videoView)

fun getSubtitles() {
    val storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference
    var srtReference = storageReference.child("Subtitles/${videoName}.srt")
    val localFile = File.createTempFile("Subtitles", "srt")
    srtReference.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener {
        videoView.addSubtitleSource(
                contentResolver.openInputStream(localFile.toUri()),
                MediaFormat.createSubtitleFormat("text/srt", Locale.ENGLISH.language)
        )
    }
}
fun playVideo(videoUrl : String){
    var uri = Uri.parse(videoUrl)
    videoView.setVideoURI(uri)
    val mediaController = MediaController(this)
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView)
    mediaController.setMediaPlayer(videoView)
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController)
    getSubtitles()
    videoView.start()
}
val videoURLRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("URL")
videoURLRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        var videoUrl = snapshot.value.toString()
        playVideo(videoUrl)
    }
    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
})
```

Playing the video works fine, and the current solution returns no errors but subtitles do not show up. There are other ways of getting data from Firebase here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files but adding to temp file seems like the best solution. Any ideas what I should change to get it working?

Comment: Your code isn't checking for errors on the download, and you're not logging anything even if it is successful. How do you know the code is running at all and doing what you expect? Also your code isn't waiting for the download to complete before starting the video. The call to getSubtitles is going to return immediately before the download even starts.

Comment: @DougStevenson Hi, I did a log right after the line .addOnSuccessListener and it logged but I deleted the line in the code shown. This tells me downloads successfully.

Comment: There is a second issue I mentioned in my last comment as well.

Comment: @DougStevenson the videoView.start() is run after the getSubtitles() function (which is supposed to add subtitle source to videoView) before playing. But I can try to call the .start() in the listener. - I will updated you

Comment: You will observe that `videoView.start()` runs before the file download callback is complete.

Comment: update: I put the .start() line after the .addSubtitleSource line and it was run. I also added a failure listener which was not triggered. The issue must be with the .addSubtitleSource() line.